# In R: How to delete specific string in specific column names

Tags: r, string, dataframe, gsub

Data Cleaning Task

I have a data frame `df` with 1000 columns, with each column name starting with `X_`. I want to delete `X_` in only the first 30 columns.

`X_col1`,`X_col2`,`X_col3`,`X_col4`,`X_col5`,`.....`,`X_col1000`.

Desired output:

`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`.....`,`col30` ; `X_col31`, `X_col32`,`.....`,`X_col1000`

`X_` should be removed in `X_col1` to `X_col30` ONLY while leaving `X_col31` to `X_col1000`

Attempt in R

```
names(df) <- gsub("X_", "", names(df)) # this removes `X_` in all 1000 columns, I only want the first 30 columns
```

Thanks

Comment: `sub("^X_(?=col(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)(?!\\d))", "", names(df), perl=TRUE)`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/44YNbk/2).

Answer (score 1):

This would do, i think

```
colnames(df)[1:30] <- gsub("X_", "", colnames(df)[1:30])
```